# wordpressのPinpoint Booking Systemプラグインについて

Tags: wordpress

wordpressのPinpoint Booking Systemプラグインは、同じ日にイベントや部屋を複数設置することはできますか。
また、その際設定はどのようにすればできますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

有料のPRO版を購入すれば可能です。
設定方法は、PRO版では左上にあるAdd Calendarが有効になっていますので、そちらから追加可能です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ちなみにPRO版はいくらかかりますか。

Comment: https://pinpoint.world/shop/product/1/pinpoint-booking-system-wordpress-plugin-pro-version

Comment: 個人向けで、1サイトに使用するのであれば年間50ドルです。いくつかの使用方法による金額が異なりますので、詳細は下記をご参照ください。https://pinpoint.world/shop/product/1/pinpoint-booking-system-wordpress-plugin-pro-version

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。参照させて頂きます。